# PHP: Converting a KML into a KMZ

Tags: php, compression, kml, kmz

I've got a custom php script that creates a KML file. Now how do I convert it into KMZ?

Should I just run `gzcompress()` on it?

Or should I create a ZipArchive?

Answer (score 4):

Creating a ZipArchive worked. I add the already created kml file to it.

```
  $zip = new ZipArchive();
  $zip_name = "c:\\kml\\".$sFilename.".kmz";
  $filename = "c:\\kml\\".$sFilename.".kml";
  $zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
  $zip->addFile($filename);
  $zip->close();
```

Comment: Ideally I want to create the KMZ directly from a string, without using the KML to save time and disk space.

Can I do this with addFromString()?  It looks like it wants to create a file within the zip archive - which I don't want to do.

Comment: Yes. addFromString works.  At least the .kmz opens with Google Earth which is a good test.